# Convert problem into SDP

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a optimization problem like:
$$min_{R,z} -\log det R $$
$$s.t. R > 0, \quad (c_i - z)^TR(c_i - z) \leq 1 \quad (i=1,\dots,k)$$.

In above problem, $c_i$ is constant $R^n$.

How can I convert the problem in the form of SDP (semidefinite programming)?

Comment: Do you really mean how to convert it to a pure vanilla SDP problem (that takes a lot of modelling as you have to replace the objective with a geometric mean of eigenvalues, and then model that...), or do you mean how to conceptually write it as a problem which can be solved by some public SDP solver which has support for more than just the SDP cone, or do you simply need to solve it and you can use a modelling layer which can do all the nasty low-level solver specifics?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean how to convert it into the pure vanilla SDP problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to show how to convert it to a pure SDP problem, as the conversion of the geometric mean operator (to replace logdet unless you use an SDP solver which handles logdet term natively, currently only SDPT3 as far as I know) is absolutely horrendous. Instead, I simply give the initial start required to linearize the model.

The constraints  $(c_i - z)^TR(c_i - z) \leq 1 $ can be written as  $(R(c_i - z))^TR^{-1}R(c_i - z) \leq 1 $ which means a Schur complement leads you to $\begin{bmatrix}1 & (R(c_i-z))^T\\ R(c_i-z) & R\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$. Define new variable $q = Rz$ and the constraint is a linear semidefinite constraint, and you have a so called MAXDET problem in $(R,q)$.

If you use a modelling layer, all the boring stuff around the logdet/geomean operator will be taken care of. If you use YALMIP in MATLAB (disclaimer: developed by me) and SDPT3 as a solver, it will be solved natively using the logdet objective, and for any other SDP solver the objective is converted to a geometric mean.
https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/maxdetprogramming/

Comment: But what if I decompose the $log det R = \sum_i \log \lambda_i$? How should I convert the constraints?

Comment: Then you are working with the log operator, which means you must have something beyond a vanilla SDP solver (mosek or scs for instance which support exponential cone programming), but that is not enough since it also requires you to create an epigraph model of eigenvalues, which is pretty messy.